# Regarding duplicate questions

Tags: bug

I was trying to post new question:

Title

> Can we use Kanji for 「びっくりした」 (surprised)?

Question:

> Can we use Kanji for 「びっくりした」(surprised) like 「吃驚した」? If so, is it
>   recommended?

And the system didn't allowed to do it, saying this is a duplicate of [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18866/can-we-use-kanji-for-%E3%82%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%86) question..

But my question is absolutely not a duplicate. Maybe this is a system error?

Comment: It does seem like a bug.  This is probably yet another example of the system ignoring non-ASCII characters, presumably because the original programmers didn't take internationalization into account.  For now, you can work around the problem by rephrasing your question.